# How can I edit a Chinese .DIC file?

Tags: dictionary, file, translate

I have a dictionary (.dic) file with some Chinese encoding, which has a long list of words inside. How can I edit that file for translating purposes? Sorry but I could not find the encoding type whatever I do.

Using Notepad++, Word or any other software I know, doesn't work. I see just complicated text.